# Run time error 1004 macos 2016

Tags: vba

Here is my code:

```
Sub SortData()
'
' SortData Macro
'

'
    Columns("A:A").Select
    Selection.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks).Select
    Selection.EntireRow.Delete
    Columns("A:A").Select
    Selection.TextToColumns Destination:=Range("A1"), DataType:=xlDelimited, _
        TextQualifier:=xlDoubleQuote, ConsecutiveDelimiter:=False, Tab:=True, _
        Semicolon:=False, Comma:=False, Space:=False, Other:=True, OtherChar _
        :=":", FieldInfo:=Array(Array(1, 1), Array(2, 1))
    Columns("A:A").Select
    ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Sort.SortFields.Clear
    ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Sort.SortFields.Add Key:=Range("A1"), _
        SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending, DataOption:=xlSortNormal
    Columns("A:A").Select
    ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Sort.SortFields.Clear
    ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Sort.SortFields.Add Key:=Range("A1"), _
        SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlDescending, DataOption:=xlSortNormal
    With ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Sort
        .SetRange Range("A2:C70")
        .Header = xlGuess
        .MatchCase = False
        .Orientation = xlTopToBottom
        .SortMethod = xlPinYin
        .Apply
    End With
End Sub
```

It says the problem is in the fourth line from the top.

This macro is trying to reorganize simple data.

Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: cell<>columns....

Comment: The fourth line from the top is an apostrophe....

Comment: `Selection.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks).Select` will fail if no cells are found (i.e. the column is empty).  Note that you should almost always avoid using the [global collections](http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/excel-vba/1107/vba-best-practices/9218/never-assume-the-worksheet#t=201612072122306662861), [`Activate`, and `Select`](http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/excel-vba/1107/vba-best-practices/9292/avoid-using-select-or-activate#t=201612072122306662861). This is also a [must read](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/how-to-avoid-using-select-in-excel-vba-macros).